# Stupidly Huge .pdf File

Tags: pdf

So I have a user that's trying to open a template .pdf file that she has reportedly been able to open and make changes to many times before, only this time she reported that it's opening/running/saving incredibly slowly.

Further investigation has revealed it to be over a gigabyte in size which is odd for a 5-page .pdf with no embedded images. This is regrettably the only copy of this particular file, but I guess technically she could take a previously edited and saved version and reverse-engineer the template, but we would rather not for unrelated reasons.

Any assistance in figuring out what is wrong with this once-1MB-file would be quite appreciated.

Comment: The file is corrupted by the sounds of it.  You could try to repair the file (search on SU for "repair pdf".

Comment: If it's only text, why not copy it and create a new one?

Comment: @Paul: from the description, the file is not corrupted, just horrendously obese.

Comment: @MaxWyss Yes, if the incremental change theory plays out, it is just big.  If it jumped from a few meg to gigabytes with minor text changes in any short period of time, then it is probably corrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF is a file format supporting incremental changes. As the OP says the file has been saved many times, this is the reason why it grew and grew and grew.

To heal the document you can do the following:

1. Quit all non-essential applications (this is optional, but it frees up memory needed by Acrobat); you might even considering restarting the computer.
2. Start Acrobat
3. Go to the Documents tab of the Acrobat Preferences
4. Uncheck "Save as optimizes for fast web view" (you may go back to this setting later on, but if your documents are not distributed via a web server, you can leave this option unchecked; in fact, if you are working with smart forms, this is the better setting anyways).
5. Confirm the changes.
6. Open the document to heal; be patient.
7. Go through the document page by page; let Acrobat time to render the pages. If that works without problems, the document can be cured.
8. Save as… under a different name. Just be patient.
9. Check the file size in the document properties. If you think it is still too much, proceed with the next steps, otherwise, you are done.
10. Select menu File --> Save as other... --> optimized PDF...
11. Click on Audit Space Usage and try to understand the results.
12. Go through all the tabs of the dialog and set things to optimize.
13. Confirm (and it will save the document again; you can select another name)
14. Go to step 9. You probably will be done.

This should get you back a healthy document. And from now on, do a Save as… regularly (I usually do it when I am done with some block of work).

Now, if there are problems in step 7, try deleting the page which causes the problem, and try again.

And another advice: If this is a document on which you work a lot, it would be worthwhile to synch it with a cloud storage service, such as Dropbox, because that would keep backups for every changed state, so that you can go back to such states.